# If I run a script on a server, should I set a virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to coding. I have deployed a few scripts on a server to automate some stuff.

All scripts are placed in the same folder.

Recently, I discovered Pycharm and I noticed that everything is organised in virtual environments. I would have to pip install the same packages for every script.

It made sense to me - this might prevent conflict.

Question: should I run every script in a virtual environment when I deploy it on a server? It takes up a lot of space though.

Thank you

Comment: I think it depends on how many scripts and how different they are. If you just have a handfull scripts with similar dependencies it is probably overkill.

Comment: I would consider virtual env only for scripts with dependencies other than the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the project is going to be bigger, it would be really useful to have a virtual environment. This will ensure that we can run different scripts requiring different versions of the same library or in case we want to host it in a repo, We can have an environment and store the dependencies in requirments.txt that way you can shift your environment to a different server as well.
It would be a good practice to have different environments and keep the base server environment as clean as possible

Comment: Understood. "We can have an environment and store the dependencies in requirments.txt" << This is a good idea. Didn't think of it. Much obliged.

Comment: And remember when you host your repository online we are expected to have a requirements.txt, then the next user can create an environment then do pip install -r requirements.txt then ur code will work as expected in other persons workspace as well